# how to set $env:PATH in powershell

Tags: powershell

If the specify the full path as below.the Path is set correctly.  Rabbitmq-service is started successfully.

```
$env:Path += ";C:\\Program Files\\erl9.2\\erts-9.2\\bin;
                C:\\Program Files\\RabbitMQ Server\\rabbitmq_server-3.6.11\\sbin;C:\\Program Files\\erl9.2\\bin"

 "Added Erlang and RabbitMQ to Path"

  # Install RabbitMQ Service and Enable Management Console
  rabbitmq-service stop     
  rabbitmq-service remove
  rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management --offline
  rabbitmq-service install
  rabbitmq-service start
```

However, if I set the PATH as below the path gets set but I run into issues in starting the rabbitmq-service. its throws an error 'ERLANG_HOME not set correctly'.Did I miss something here?

```
$ERLANG_HOME = "$env:PROGRAMFILES\erl9.2"
$ERTS_HOME = "$env:PROGRAMFILES\erts-9.2"
$RABBITMQ_HOME = "$env:PROGRAMFILES\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.11"

$env:Path += ";$ERTS_HOME\\bin;$RABBITMQ_HOME\\sbin;$ERLANG_HOME\\bin"

"Added Erlang and RabbitMQ to Path"

# Install RabbitMQ Service and Enable Management Console
rabbitmq-service stop   
rabbitmq-service remove
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management --offline
rabbitmq-service install
rabbitmq-service start
```

Comment: the 2nd one does not have the doubled slashes [only singles] for the part in the $Vars that you have in the 1st example.

Comment: Could you post the substituted `$env:Path` value as part of the question, please? Maybe do a `Write-Host $env:Path` before the rabbitmq commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $env:ERLANG_HOME instead of $ERLANG_HOME sets the path correctly.

```
$env:ERLANG_HOME = "$env:PROGRAMFILES\erl9.2"
$env:ERTS_HOME = "$env:PROGRAMFILES\erl9.2\erts-9.2"
$env:RABBITMQ_HOME = "$env:PROGRAMFILES\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.11"

$env:PATH += ";$env:ERLANG_HOME\bin;$env:ERTS_HOME\bin;$env:RABBITMQ_HOME\sbin"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$env:ERLANG_HOME = "$env:ProgramFiles\erl9.0"
$env:ERTS_HOME = "$env:ProgramFiles\erl9.0\erts-9.0"
$env:RABBITMQ_HOME = "$env:ProgramFiles\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.12"
$env:PATH += ";$env:ERLANG_HOME\bin;$env:ERTS_HOME\bin;$env:RABBITMQ_HOME\sbin"
rabbitmq-service stop 
rabbitmq-service remove
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management --offline
rabbitmq-service install
rabbitmq-service start
```

Did the above worked for me in PowerShell v 5.1. thank you both